# Transform DateTime into simple Date from mysql when rendering page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, datatable

I am developing a datatable in Ruby on Rails, but I don't understand how to translate mysql datetime into normal date notation within the datatable when rending the view.

Roughly, I have my table view that imports the columns.

```
<div class="content-main">
    <table id="customer-grid" data-grid-name="Customers List" data-available-columns='[<%=raw(@grid_fields.map{|fieldcaption,fieldname| '"'<<fieldcaption<<'"'}.join(",") )%>]' data-column_scaling='<%=raw(@grid_fields_scaling.map{|fieldcaption,scale| scale}.join(",") )%>' >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <% @grid_fields_visible.each do |fieldcaption,fieldname|%>
                    <th><%=fieldcaption%></th>
                <%end%>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The columns list is given by the controller of the page.

```
@grid_fields=@grid_service.get_grid_fields
@grid_fields_visible =@grid_service.get_grid_fields_visible
```

that brings to the actual list in the service folder.

```
def get_grid_fields
    return {
        "Company Name"      =>"name",
        "Contact Name"      =>"contact_name",
        "Address"           =>"address_1",
        "Post Code"         =>"postcode",
        "Telephone"         =>"tel",
        "Primary Email"     =>"email",
        "WWW"               =>"www",
        "Created by"        =>"created_by",
        "Date Created"      =>"created_at",
        "Modified by"       =>"modified_by",
        "Date modified"     =>"modified_at"
    }
end
```

The mysql connection is given by a module:

```
module CustomerLegacyShim extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    self.table_name = "tblcustomers"

    ...
    alias_attribute :created_by,       :tblCustomer_CreatedBy
    alias_attribute :created_at,       :tblCustomer_CreatedAt
    alias_attribute :modified_by,      :tblCustomer_ModifiedBy
    alias_attribute :modified_at,      :tblCustomer_ModifiedAt

    ...
  end
end
```

To go to the point, everything works great. The only problem is that I have a really incomprehensible DateTime, and I don't understand what to change to make it %d/%m/%Y within the table.

The fact is that I completely have no idea where to put .strftime() or .strptime(), as I can only give the "column name" to the datatable and I don't know how to change the format of the retrieved data.

Can anybody teach me?

Luca

Comment: I added an answer with the links to the docs that will give you something to start with. There're many ways to play with date and datetime. You should try to play with them in the rails console or in irb.

Answer (score 0):

You can use to_s(:db) to convert into a database friendly format.

```
Time.now.to_s(:db)
```

However, timezone specified in Rails because the time will be stored in UTC in the database. You'll need to specify that to do proper comparisons.
Time.now.to_s(:db)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `to_date` to get a Date object.

```
time = Time.now
date = time.to_date
```

Then you can use `strftime` to get the output you need:

```
date.strftime('%a %d %b %Y')    #=> "Sun 04 Feb 2001"
```

Or in the format that you need:

```
date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') #=> "02/06/2016"
```

Here is the doc for the Date class: [link](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html)

And more info on `strftime` format: [link](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime)

Now let say I have this in a controller:

```
@my_objects = MyObject.all
```

In the views you can do something like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>Create at</td> 
  </tr>
  <% @my_objects.each do |0| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= o.title%></td>
      <td><%= o.created_at.to_date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') %></td> 
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I had to hard code the datatable column and create a dedicated function within the *.dataTable method in JS:

```
"columnDefs": [
    {
        "sClass": "date-long filterdaterangedatetime",
        "targets": getColumnIndexFromName('#sage-customers-grid',['Date Created','Date modified']),
        "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
            if (data != "") {
                var date = data.substring(0,10);
                var dateParts = date.split("-");
                var createDataFormat = dateParts[2] + "/" + dateParts[1] + "/" + dateParts[0];
                return createDataFormat;
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        }
    }
]
```